# Count number of instructions of various types using LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm a new user to the LLVM Compiler Infrastructure. I've gone through the LLVM Programmer's Manual Documentation and understood how to iterate over basic blocks. I wanted to know whether there are any predefined passes for counting instructions. I understand there is instcount, but that returns the total number of instructions. I'm targeting primarily integer and floating point operations. Also what should I do in cases where there are operands of different types in an expression?

Comment: Your last sentence seem to be a question in itself, maybe it's worth asking it separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InstCount` pass already has a separate counter for each instruction type, in addition to a total instruction count. For example, the number of `add` instructions will be stored in the `NumAddInst` statistic variable. You can use that pass or reuse some of its code.